# Vscode : How I can add module for other python interpreter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

Hi! I tried to use python 3.8 in vscode.
But when I changed the version of interpreter, my modules made error.
So after changed the interpreter from 3.10.5 to 3.8.9,I input pip3 install 000.
But, That is not working.

How I can handle this?

1. How I can change the main version of python in VScode
2. How I can add library for my sub python interpreter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you can use "ctrl+shift+P" to choose your python interpreter. And for jupyter file, you can change the kernel by clicking the button in your picture:

[image]

For the second question,usually, when you select an interpreter, pip will  automatically install the package into the library under the selected interpreter. You can use the following command:

```
pip install packageName --target="sub python path"
```

Comment: However, when I tried that, pip3 install pandas --target="3.8.9", it is working on terminal but not be seen on the packages....T.T

Comment: @Kyungyun Lee It's path instead of version. For example,"pip3 install pandas --target=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages"